# Mapping computed properties in Linq-to-SQL to actuall SQL statements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have created some extra functionality on my Linq-to-SQL classes to make things easier as I develop my applications. For example I have defined a property that retrieves active contracts from a list of contracts. However if I try to use this property in a lambda expression or in general in a query it either throws an exception that there is no SQL statement matching that property or it generates one query per item (= a lot of roundtrips to the server).

The queries themselves are not overly complex f.ex:

```
var activeContracts = customer.Contracts.Where(w => w.ContractEndDate == null);
```

Whereas I would like it to read as:

```
var activeContracts = customer.ActiveContracts;
```

The main reason for me doing this is because it will minimize logical errors on my part and if I in the future want to change what defines an active contract I don't have to redo a lot of code.

Is there a way to specify on a property what SQL it should genereate. Or is there a way to make sure it is usable in a query like below?

```
var singleContractCustomers = db.Customers.Where(w => w.ActiveContracts.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: What is the type of your property?

Comment: I have used both simple ones like bool and complex ones like IQueryable<Contract> and it produces roughly the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessed individually, I suspect that having a query that returns IQueryable would work - however, I expect that when this is part of a larger Expression, the expression interpreter will complain (which seems like what you are describing).

However, I suspect that you might be able to break it down a bit. Try adding (to customer):

```
    public static Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> HasActiveContract
    {
        get { return cust => cust.Contracts.Count() == 1; }
    }
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
    var filtered = db.Customers.Where(Customer.HasActiveContract);
```

Obviously it is hard to run it (from here) to see what TSQL it comes up with, but I'd be surprised if that does roundtrips; I would expect that to do the COUNT() in the TSQL. As a topmost query, you should also be able to wrap this:

```
    public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersWithActiveContract
    {
        get { return Customers.Where(Customer.HasActiveContract); }
    }
```

Does any of that work?

Answer (score 1):

That worked like a charm. The SQL statment generated by **CustomersWithActiveContracts** looked fine to me.

```
{SELECT [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[cFirstName], [t0].[cLastName]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM [dbo].[Contracts] AS [t1]
    WHERE (([t1].[ContractEndDate] > @p0) OR ([t1].[ContractEndDate] IS NULL)) AND ([t1].[cId] = [t0].[cId])
    )) > @p1
}
```

It should also mean that it's possible to build on this query without it generating more trips to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the use the [Microsoft.Linq.Translations](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider) library. This will allow you to define your property and it's Linq translation as follows:

```
partial class Customer
{
    private static readonly CompiledExpression<Employee,IEnumerable<Contract>> activeContractsExpression
        = DefaultTranslationOf<Customer>
          .Property(c => c.ActiveContracts)
          .Is(c => c.Contracts.Where(x => x.ContractEndDate == null));

    public IEnumerable<Contract> ActiveContracts
    {
        get 
        { 
            // This is only called when you access your property outside a query
            return activeContractsExpression.Evaluate(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can query it like so:

```
var singleContractCustomers = db.Customers.WithTranslations()
                              .Where(w => w.ActiveContracts.Count() == 1);
```

Notice the call to `WithTranslations()`. This creates a special wrapping `IQueryable` that will replace all references to your computed property with its translation before the query expression is passed off to Linq to SQL.

Also, if you include the `Microsoft.Linq.Translations.Auto` namespace instead of `System.Linq`, then you do not even need to call `WithTranslations()`!